# What is the purpose of iocharset=utf8?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I see `iocharset=utf8` recommended nearly everywhere when mounting Windows SMB shares into Linux.

I have mounted vhdx files to a Ubuntu VM that I want to be assured that whatever files I write to the disk from the Ubuntu VM will be readable from Windows in the future. Therefore I have two questions:

1. Is this what `iocharset=utf8` does?
2. Should I apply this option to the fstab for the vhdx in the Ubuntu VM too, and not just SMB shares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iocharset=utf8` sets what encoding to use when mounting drives or network shares.

According to Wikipedia:

```
UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible characters, or code points, defined by Unicode.
```

It's pretty much a safety feature just to make sure Ubuntu can present all text in a readable format (shows it correctly), and save everything in a format readable by other OSes.

You certainly can add this option to anything you mount, but unless you encounter problems with text or file paths, there's no need to add it.

Answer (score 8):

The [default](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) character encoding for the mounts in Linux is iso8859-1. This encoding is [legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622091/207661) and only supports 256 characters. All modern systems should be using utf-8 but I think default is left at ISO8859-1 for compatibility reasons. So it's always good idea to add iocharset=utf8 when mounting Windows share. Also, lot of websites enforces filemode/dirmod 777 when mounting which I think are unnecessary. The mount command that I use is,

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER/FOLDER /mnt/FOLDER -o username=USER,domain=DOMAIN,iocharset=utf8
```